# Magento First name cannot be empty,invalid email address

Tags: magento, checkout, billing

On checkout there is an error:

"The first name cannot be empty.,Invalid email address"". These fields are filled!

```
public function validate()
{
    $errors = array();
    if (!Zend_Validate::is( trim($this->getFirstname()) , 'NotEmpty')) {
        $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('The first name cannot be empty.');
    }

    if (!Zend_Validate::is( trim($this->getLastname()) , 'NotEmpty')) {
       $this->setLastname();
    }

    if (!Zend_Validate::is($this->getEmail(), 'EmailAddress')) {
         $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Invalid email address "%s".', $this->getEmail());
    }

    $password = $this->getPassword();
    if (!$this->getId() && !Zend_Validate::is($password , 'NotEmpty')) {
        $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('The password cannot be empty.');
    }
    if (strlen($password) && !Zend_Validate::is($password, 'StringLength', array(6))) {
        $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('The minimum password length is %s', 6);
    }
    $confirmation = $this->getConfirmation();
    if ($password != $confirmation) {
        $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Please make sure your passwords match.');
    }
    $entityType = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getEntityType('customer');
    $attribute = Mage::getModel('customer/attribute')->loadByCode($entityType, 'dob');
    if ($attribute->getIsRequired() && '' == trim($this->getDob())) {
        $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('The Date of Birth is required.');
    }
    $attribute = Mage::getModel('customer/attribute')->loadByCode($entityType, 'taxvat');
    if ($attribute->getIsRequired() && '' == trim($this->getTaxvat())) {
        $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('The TAX/VAT number is required.');
    }
    $attribute = Mage::getModel('customer/attribute')->loadByCode($entityType, 'gender');
    if ($attribute->getIsRequired() && '' == trim($this->getGender())) {
        $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Gender is required.');
    }

    if (empty($errors)) {
        return true;
    }
    return $errors;
}
```

Please help me..

Comment: do you use any special modules on the checkout page ?

Comment: I use free swift onepagecheckout module for the checkout, but it was working ok..how to check the error?

Comment: you can make Mage::log('the firstname is '.$this->getFirstname()) and check the system.log in var/log/

Comment: Christophe, do I have to create a file with the code you privide and check online?thanks.

Comment: for a while you can put it in the core file but don't let it there after testing...

Comment: Christophe I didn't understood you very well. Do I have to put de code into what file? and then check it online?

Comment: you need to put it in Mage/Catalog/Model/Product in the function validate but don't put it online, just test it locally... i thought you knew where is this function as you pasted the code.

Comment: Christophe, could you please contact me at yoligrana@gmail.com I need urgent help, thanks.

Comment: The issue is not fixed yet...what can I do?

Comment: as said by chat, without entire code and a bit of time, I cannot help you. sorry.